# OData Expand Child of Child Missing Key Exception

Tags: .net-core, odata

AspNetCore 3.1 web app with OData version 7.5.2 installed.

I am getting an exception when I do a child of child expand:

i.e.

> https://localhost:5001/clinic?$expand=clients($expand=allergies)

If I just expand on clients with clinic - it works fine

> https://localhost:5001/clinic?$expand=clients

or clients expanded with allergies - it works.

> https://localhost:5001/client?$expand=allergies

The second level of expansion is throwing the error.

[image]

I have entities defined:

```
public class Clinic 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string PhoneDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }

    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public ClientStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public Guid ClinicId { get; set; }

    public virtual Clinic Clinic { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClientAllergy> Allergies { get; set; }
}

public class ClientAllergy 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Allergy { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }
    public string Reaction { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

The EdmModel is built:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.Expand().Select().OrderBy().Filter();
            endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection();
            endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "", GetEdmModel());
        });
    }
    
    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Clinic>("Clinics");
        builder.EntitySet<Client>("Clients");
        builder.EntitySet<Application>("Applications");
        builder.EntitySet<ClientAllergy>("ClientAllergies");
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

And the $metadata page looks to be correctly registering the entities.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="4.0" xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
<edmx:DataServices>
    <Schema Namespace="ABC.Data.Entity" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
        <EntityType Name="Clinic">
            <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Key>
            <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="Street" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="Unit" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="City" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="State" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="Zipcode" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="PhoneNumber" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="PhoneDescription" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="Created" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="Modified" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="ApplicationId" Type="Edm.Guid" />
            <NavigationProperty Name="Application" Type="ABC.Data.Entity.Application">
                <ReferentialConstraint Property="ApplicationId" ReferencedProperty="Id" />
            </NavigationProperty>
            <NavigationProperty Name="Clients" Type="Collection(ABC.Data.Entity.Client)" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Client">
            <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Key>
            <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="LastName" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="FirstName" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="MiddleName" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="Street" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="Unit" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="City" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="State" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="Zipcode" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="DateOfBirth" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="Status" Type="ABC.Data.Entity.ClientStatus" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="Created" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="Modified" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="ClinicId" Type="Edm.Guid" />
            <NavigationProperty Name="Clinic" Type="ABC.Data.Entity.Clinic">
                <ReferentialConstraint Property="ClinicId" ReferencedProperty="Id" />
            </NavigationProperty>
            <NavigationProperty Name="Allergies" Type="Collection(ABC.Data.Entity.ClientAllergy)" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Application">
            <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Key>
            <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="Created" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="Modified" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false" />
            <NavigationProperty Name="Partners" Type="Collection(ABC.Data.Entity.Clinic)" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="ClientAllergy">
            <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Key>
            <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="Allergy" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="AdditionalInformation" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="Reaction" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="Created" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="Modified" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="ClientId" Type="Edm.Guid" />
            <NavigationProperty Name="Client" Type="ABC.Data.Entity.Client">
                <ReferentialConstraint Property="ClientId" ReferencedProperty="Id" />
            </NavigationProperty>
        </EntityType>
        <EnumType Name="ClientStatus">
            <Member Name="Active" Value="0" />
            <Member Name="Deceased" Value="1" />
            <Member Name="DMC" Value="2" />
            <Member Name="NotAssess" Value="3" />
            <Member Name="OnHold" Value="4" />
        </EnumType>
    </Schema>
    <Schema Namespace="Default" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
        <EntityContainer Name="Container">
            <EntitySet Name="Clinics" EntityType="ABC.Data.Entity.Clinic">
                <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="Application" Target="Applications" />
                <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="Clients" Target="Clients" />
            </EntitySet>
            <EntitySet Name="Clients" EntityType="ABC.Data.Entity.Client">
                <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="Allergies" Target="ClientAllergies" />
                <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="Clinic" Target="Clinics" />
            </EntitySet>
            <EntitySet Name="Applications" EntityType="ABC.Data.Entity.Application">
                <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="Partners" Target="Clinics" />
            </EntitySet>
            <EntitySet Name="ClientAllergies" EntityType="ABC.Data.Entity.ClientAllergy">
                <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="Client" Target="Clients" />
            </EntitySet>
        </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a *Data* related issue, your schema looks correct.
The giveaway here is that the error is raised when the objects are being *materialized* from the data provider into the *OData Model*, there are many more steps in the stack trace that would be expected if this occurred later in serialization.

Query the same allergies from the database using EF in a unit test or directly in your data store (assuming SQL). If you see any with a `NULL` value for the Id, then you should fix or remove those records.

A further proof is to try this query:

```
https://localhost:5001/clinic?$expand=clients($expand=allergies;$filter=Id ne null)
```